# Is there a way to use a Bootstrap popover inside a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, nhibernate

I'm in an nHibernate-driven MVC environment. My view calls up several nested HTML content tabs, and in those tabs I have Modal pop-ups based on clicked items in displayed grids.

I'd like to use the Bootstrap popover tooltip on the fields inside that modal, but I can't seem to get them to work.

The main View is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Bootstrap.Base.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CTICNWv4.Framework.AppContext.ICurrentApplicationContext>" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" ID="tc" runat="server">
    Chicago Title School of Real Estate Management
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" ID="pc" runat="server">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12" style="text-align: right;"><a href="/Employee/#!Schools">< Back to Employee Dashboard</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid" id="divWOW">
        <div class="span12">
            <h1>School Management</h1>

            <div id="ng-app" ng-app="schoolManager" class="tabbable tabs-left">
                <ul ng-controller="NavCtrl" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/scheduling/active') }"><a href="#/scheduling/active">Scheduling</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/classes') }"><a href="#/classes">Classes</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/venues') }"><a href="#/venues">Venues</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/instructors') }"><a href="#/instructors">Instructors</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/closed-classes') }"><a href="#/closed-classes">Closed Classes</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/scheduling/canceled') }"><a href="#/scheduling/canceled">Canceled Classes</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div ng-view growl class="tab-content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="AdditionalScripts" ID="as" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-addons/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-addons/jquery.bootstrap-growl.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ng-v4/ng-v4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/schoolmanager/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/schoolmanager/controllers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/schoolmanager/services.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.tenant = '<%= V4AppCtx.Current.TenantInfo.Operation %>';
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="AdditionalContent" ID="ac" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .nav, .pagination, .carousel a {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
```

And the HTML sub-tab code page is:

```
<div ng-hide="resourcesLoaded >= 4" class="alert alert-warning">
    <h4>Loading...</h4>
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
        <div class="bar" style="width: 1000%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-show="resourcesLoaded >= 4">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            <button class="btn" ng-click="newClass()" ng-disabled="!options.createNew"><i class="icon-plus"></i>New Class</button>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <input type="text" class="pull-right" placeholder="Search" ng-model="filter" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Course Date</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Venue City</th>
                <th>Clock Hrs.</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody highlight highlight-selector="tr#i_{{identifier}}>td">
            <tr ng-repeat="item in classes | filter:filter | orderBy:courseSort:true | startAt:(currentPage-1)*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize"
                ng-click="editClass(item)" class="clickable" id="i_{{item.ScheduleId}}">
                <td>{{item.Class.CourseDate}}</td>
                <td>({{item.Class.CourseNum}}) {{item.Class.ClassName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Class.VenueCity}}</td>
                <td>{{item.Class.ClockHrs}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <pagination total-items="classes.length" page="currentPage" items-per-page="pageSize"></pagination>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="class-form.html">
    <form name="form" novalidate ng-submit="ok('save')">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 ng-hide="!item.ScheduleId || closeout.show">Edit Class</h3>
            <h3 ng-hide="!closeout.show">Closeout</h3>
            <h3 ng-hide="item.ScheduleId">New Class</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body" ng-hide="closeout.show">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error:form.course.$invalid && form.course.$dirty}">
                        <label for="course">Course *</label>
                        <select id="course" name="course" ng-model="item.Class.ClassId" class="input-block-level" ng-options="c.ClassId as ('(' + c.CourseNum + ') ' + c.ClassName) for c in courses | filter:{Active:true}" required 
                        title="Select a Course from the list. This field is required."
                        data-content="Select a Course from the list. This field is required."
                        rel="popover" 
                        data-placement="right" 
                        data-original-title="Course"></select>
                        <span ng-show="form.course.$dirty">
                            <span ng-show="form.course.$error.required" class="help-inline">Please choose a course</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error:form.venue.$invalid && form.venue.$dirty}">
                        <label for="venue">Venue *</label>
                        <select id="venue" name="venue" ng-model="item.Class.VenueId" class="input-block-level" ng-options="v.VenueId as (v.Name + ' (' + v.City + ')') for v in venues | filter:{Active:true}" required 
                        title="Select a Venue from the list. This field is required."
                        data-content="Select a Venue from the list. This field is required."
                        rel="popover" 
                        data-placement="right" 
                        data-original-title="Venue"></select>
                        <span ng-show="form.venue.$dirty">
                            <span ng-show="form.venue.$error.required" class="help-inline">Please choose a venue</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error:form.date.$invalid && form.date.$dirty}">
                        <label for="date">Date *</label>
                        <div class="input-prepend input-block-level">
                            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
                            <input id="date" name="date" type="text" ng-model="item.Class.CourseDate" required ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,2}[/-][0-9]{1,2}[/-][0-9]{2,4}$/" 
                            placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" 
                            title="Please enter the class date, formatted as Month(2 Digit)/Day(2 Digit)/Year(4 Digit). This field is required."
                            data-content="Please enter the class date, formatted as Month(2 Digit)/Day(2 Digit)/Year(4 Digit). This field is required.

Example: 12/21/2014"
                            rel="popover" 
                            data-placement="right" 
                            data-original-title="Date">
                        </div>
                        <span ng-show="form.date.$dirty">
                            <span ng-show="form.date.$error.required" class="help-inline">Date is required</span>
                            <span ng-show="form.date.$error.pattern" class="help-inline">Invalid date</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error:form.time.$invalid && form.time.$dirty}">
                        <label for="time">Time *</label>
                        <div class="input-prepend input-block-level">
                            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
                            <input id="time" name="time" type="text" ng-model="item.Class.StartTime" required ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}[ ]*[AaPp][Mm]$/" 
                            placeholder="HH:MM AM/PM" 
                            title="Please enter the class time, formatted as Hours:Minutes AM or PM. This field is required, and the 'AM' or 'PM' is required."
                            data-content="Please enter the class time, formatted as Hours:Minutes AM or PM. This field is required, and the 'AM' or 'PM' is required.

Example: 08:15 AM
Example: 03:42 PM"
                            rel="popover" 
                            data-placement="right" 
                            data-original-title="Time">
                        </div>
                        <span ng-show="form.time.$dirty">
                            <span ng-show="form.time.$error.required" class="help-inline">Time is required</span>
                            <span ng-show="form.time.$error.pattern" class="help-inline">Invalid time</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error:form.cost.$invalid && form.cost.$dirty}">
                        <label for="cost">Cost</label>
                        <div class="input-prepend input-block-level">
                            <span class="add-on">$</span>
                            <input id="cost" name="cost" type="text" ng-model="item.Class.Cost" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*[.]*[0-9]*$/" 
                            placeholder="#,###.##" 
                            title="Please enter the cost of the class. The cost should be entered as a monetary amount. This field is not required."
                            data-content="Please enter the cost of the class. The cost should be entered as a monetary amount. This field is not required."
                            rel="popover" 
                            data-placement="right" 
                            data-original-title="Cost">
                        </div>
                        <span ng-show="form.cost.$dirty">
                            <span ng-show="form.cost.$error.required" class="help-inline">Cost is required</span>
                            <span ng-show="form.cost.$error.pattern" class="help-inline">Invalid amount</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label>
                    <label for="private" class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="private" ng-model="item.Class.Private" /> Private
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error:form.comment.$invalid && form.comment.$dirty}">
                        <label for="comment">Compliance Comment</label>
                        <textarea id="comment" name="comment" type="text" ng-model="item.Class.ComplianceComment" class="input-block-level" rows="3" maxlength="128" 
                        placeholder="Enter Compliance content here." 
                        title="Please use this area to enter any Compliance notes for this class. This field is not required."
                        data-content="Please use this area to enter any Compliance notes for this class. This field is not required."
                        rel="popover" 
                        data-placement="right" 
                        data-original-title="Compliance Comment"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <label>Instructors</label>
                    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Instructor</th>
                                <th>Primary?</th>
                                <th>Show Contact Info?</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="inst in item.Instructors">
                                <td>{{inst.FirstName}} {{inst.LastName}}</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="inst.Primary"></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="inst.ShowContactInfo"></td>
                                <td class="centered"><a class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" ng-click="removeInstructor(inst)"><i class="icon-remove"></i> Remove</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><select id="instructor" name="instructor" class="input-block-level" ng-model="newInstructor.InstructorId" ng-options="inst.InstructorId as inst.FullName for inst in instructors | filter:{Active:true}"
                                title="Please select an Instructor from the list. This field is not required."
                                data-content="Please select an Instructor from the list. This field is not required."
                                rel="popover" 
                                data-placement="right" 
                                data-original-title="Compliance Comment"></select></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="newInstructor.Primary"></td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="newInstructor.ShowContactInfo"></td>
                                <td class="centered"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" ng-click="addInstructor()"><i class="icon-plus"></i> Add</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" ng-hide="closeout.show">
            <span ng-hide="!item.ScheduleId" class="pull-left">
                <span ng-show="options.cancel"><confirm-button text="Cancel Class" body="Are you sure you want to cancel this class?  An email will be sent to the RSVP'd students." action="ok('cancel-class')"></confirm-button></span>
                <button class="btn" disabled="true" ng-show="!options.cancel">Cancel Class</button>
                <button class="btn" ng-click="showCloseOut()" ng-disabled="!options.closeOut" type="button">Closeout</button>
            </span>

            <span ng-show="form.$invalid">
                * Please enter all required information before saving.
            </span>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" type="submit">Save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body" ng-hide="!closeout.show">
            <div ng-show="!closeout.closingOut && !closeout.closedOut">
                <p>
                    Please verify (and update as needed) the payment and completion status for the following students. 
                    This list only shows students who have not cancelled their RSVPs and signed-in on the day of class.
                </p>

                <div ng-show="!closeout.rsvps" class="alert alert-info">
                    Loading students...
                </div>

                <div ng-show="closeout.rsvps && closeout.rsvps.length == 0" class="alert alert-warning">
                    No students for this class.
                </div>

                <table class="table table-condensed" ng-show="closeout.rsvps && closeout.rsvps.length > 0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Student Name</th>
                            <th class="centered">Paid?</th>
                            <th class="centered">Completed?</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="rsvp in closeout.rsvps">
                            <td>{{rsvp.FirstName}} {{rsvp.LastName}}</td>
                            <td class="centered"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="rsvp.Paid" disabled></td>
                            <td class="centered"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="rsvp.Completed"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <p>
                    <strong>If you are finished verifying the information above, you may proceed to Closeout this class or 
                    Cancel (and return to the previous screen).</strong>
                </p>

                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <h4>Note:</h4>
                    Only students who paid for and completed the class will receive a certificate and notification thereof.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="closeout.closingOut && !closeout.closedOut">
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    Please wait while the class is closed out...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="closeout.closedOut">
                <p>The Class has been closed. Any students who attended, paid for and completed the class will be receiving a Thank You email with information on retreiving their certificate.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer" ng-hide="!closeout.show">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doCloseOut()" ng-disabled="!closeout.rsvps" ng-hide="closeout.closingOut || closeout.closedOut">Closeout</button>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancelCloseOut()" ng-hide="closeout.closingOut || closeout.closedOut">Cancel</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok('closedout')" ng-show="closeout.closedOut">OK</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ container: ".modal-body" });
    $('#course').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
    $('#venue').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
    $('#date').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
    $('#time').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
    $('#cost').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
    $('#comment').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
    $('#instructor').popover({ trigger: "hover" });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the container for your popover to the modal dialog.

```
//#modalDialog would be whatever the ID is for your modal dialog div.
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ container: "#modalDialog" });
```

<s>Edit: I just noticed you do yours on #comment, but I don't see any elements with the id `comment`.</s>

Your container doesn't have to be a div with the ID modalDialog. In your case I'd try making the container `.modal-body`, you should get the desired effect. Also, this will only apply to popovers that have the `data-toggle` attribute, you can either leave that or change it to whatever selector would apply to all your popover elements.

Comment: Any thoughts on this again, now that the full code is posted? (For instance, other methods, given that there is no modal div.)

Comment: added `$('[data-toggle="popover"]', container).popover({ container: ".modal-body" });` to my script at the bottom of the sub-tab code... and the whole tab stopped working. I'm guessing I'm still doing something hideously wrong.

Comment: Gah, sorry my bad, I left in a piece of my code that is relevant to my site but not yours. Strip out the `container` aspect from the selector part. I'll modify my post as well.

Comment: Adding change to the code, because this inline stuff blows.

Comment: Ah, so you're saying that since I'm using Hover on mine, I'm sort of screwed? Or do I just need to add in the data-toggle to my existing objects?

Comment: No you can still use the hover. Bootstrap uses a convention of `data-api`s to hookup some of it's components that require JS to function, but tooltips and popovers don't get setup automatically due to  performance reasons, you must opt-in to enable them. If you use the data-toggle practice as the site suggests, the default method to opt-in is to use `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();`. This replies on your tags to have the attribute `data-toggle="popover"`, to make it operate on hover then you would add `data-trigger="hover"` to the tag. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage